# How to use Styled Markers after Google Charts deprecation

Tags: javascript, gmlib

I know what the problem is, but not how to fix it.

Some time ago, Google removed StyledMarker.js from its libraries, and the fix was to host it elsewhere. This Javascript references https://chart.googleapis.com (L.44), and this URL has now been deprecated (Mar 14 2019, see https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/).

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://webapps.stackexchange.com/